# Question about exotic spheres 

Tags: differential-topology

From what I understand, an exotic n-sphere is a manifold which is homeomorphic to the n-sphere but not diffeomorphic to it.
Now I have read that there are no exotic 2-spheres.
But isn't something like a tetrahedron an example of a manifold which is homeomorphic to the sphere, but not diffeomorphic ? (Because of the corners and edges.)
What am I missing ?

Comment: You are missing the definition of a manifold, I guess. Tetrahedron is not a manifold if you don't specify atlases on it.

Comment: I believe you're confusing properties of an embedding of a sphere in 3-space with its intrinsic differentiable structure

Comment: A exotic sphere is (by definition) a differentiable manifold. So if you want to consider the tetrahedron, you have to specify, what differentiability at one of the edges means. As soon as you specified this, you will just get the 2-sphere-.

Comment: On the other hand, some subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (e.g. a sphere, a torus) are accepted as manifolds w/o specifying an atlas. I think the situation is that if there is a "well-known" submersion such with this subset is one of the fibers, then this subset is accepted by community as a manifold. (A neccesary condition then is for this subset to have a unique tangent space at each point, so tetrahedron fails to satisfy this condition and you don't need to try to find a relevant submersion.)

Comment: @HerinkRüping: You should repost your comment as an answer so that Cosmonut can accept it.

Comment: Thanks Henrik, that makes a lot of sense !
So, loosely speaking, once you make the tetrahedron a differentiable manifold, you've smoothened away the corners and edges. I see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A exotic sphere is (by definition) a differentiable manifold. So if you want to consider the tetrahedron, you have to specify, what differentiability at one of the edges means. As soon as you specified this, you will just get the 2-sphere.